# Setting fixed delay between jmeter ThreadGroup loop iterations

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I am performing load test of web component which receives files from users and later sends them back on demand. For this I am uploading files to web component with maximum number of concurrent users. I want to simulate an environment where:

100 simultaneous users will be sending continuous upload file requests to some web application. There would be delay of exactly 1 second between two consecutive requests from same user regardless of last request sent by same user is completed or not. In short 100 users will send upload file request simultaneously, then each user will wait for 1 seconds and again all 100 users will send next upload request and the process continues. I want to make this configuration with help of Jmeter.

User(1) => Send upload request, wait 1 second, Send upload request, wait 1 second, continue..

User(2) => Send upload request, wait 1 second, Send upload request, wait 1 second, continue..

User(3) => Send upload request, wait 1 second, Send upload request, wait 1 second, continue..

.

.

.

.

User(100) => Send upload request, wait 1 second, Send upload request, wait 1 second, continue..

Currently I have structure:

```
   ThreadGroup(Number of Threads: 100, Ramp up Period: 1 second, Loop count: Forever)
   ----HTTP Header Manager
   ----HTTP Request
   ----View Results in Table
```

But each next iteration of loop waits till last iteration's requests are served successfully. I want to change this behavior so that next iteration will start even if last iteration's requests are not served yet.

Any help/suggestions/improvements are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use Timer in between requests 
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#timers